# ExactTarget: URL in a variable - not tracked

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I believe I've come across a bug.  I wondered if anyone else have come up with a solution for this?

```
%%[
set @bodycopy = "Visit the all new whatever I'm talking 
                 about. <a href=""http://www.whatever.con/"">Click here!!</a>"
]%%
%%=v(@bodycopy)=%%
```

*(Spacing/linebreak added to code for legibility on StackExchange.)*

The HREF doesn't go to ExactTarget and counted as a click.  It renders fine and the click functions perfectly as far as the subscriber is concerned (perhaps even faster than tracked links) but I don't get credit for the click.

I've also tried

```
set @bodycopy = Concat("Visit the all new whatever I'm talking about. <a
                href=""", @RedirectTo("http://www.whatever.con/"),""">Click
                here!!</a>")
```

*(Spacing/linebreak added to code for legibility on StackExchange.)*

with the same results.

I don't have the luxury of splitting the variable into multiple parts or just rendering in HTML.  As near as I can tell...

The options I can think of...

- I have the link in my variable and don't track it
- throw out my entire template for these rare cases with a link
- refactor my code to have four variables (before link, link url, link copy, after link) for these rare cases
- convince Salesforce they have a bug
- manually insert the http://click.em.whatever.con in front of the final destination (if that's possible?)

I'll be forever grateful if someone's got a solve or another option I haven't thought of.

Comment: Relevant: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54646/links-generated-in-the-ampscript-block-are-not-being-tracked

Comment: Thanks, Adam, that did indeed work.  I guess I need to share that with the SFMC Technical Architect assigned to our account.  They said I'd need to refactor all my templates and shared content modules.

Comment: Oh... can you explain S1 from this documentation?  http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TreatAsContentArea

Scenario: I might reuse @ bodycopy multiple times in the same email: Three modules with the same layout.  I might also have 8 translated versions.  So let's say 24 distinct @ bodycopys get defined.  Do I need a different s1 for each of them?

Comment: It's for caching and limiting the link-wrapping of content area.  Once you've assigned a key to a Content Area it becomes read-only.

Comment: Yes.  That's the way I understand it.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment, it seemed more appropriate to be its own question.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104365/can-someone-help-me-understand-treatascontentarea but I guess that's not too onerous if I just need a second variable with each time I invoke with unique content.  Appreciate your help.