# Is it possible to suppress link tracking on a single link

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

We've instituted a custom unsubscribe solution for our email marketing.  Since this link is an outbound link, SFMC treats clicks on this link in the same way as all other link clicks. Is there a way to suppress click tracking to this one link so they don't show up in our reporting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way would be to obfuscate the link. Try the following code:

```
%%[
var @unsubLink
set @unsubLink = Base64Encode('<a href="http://domain.com/unsubscribe">unsubscribe</a>')
]%%

%%=Base64Decode(@unsubLink)=%%
```

Using this code, the `@unsubLink` is not tracked, but all other links in the email are tracked.

Comment: Great answer - you can also utilize a bug that has been plaguing SFMC for a bit - see more info here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141332/possible-to-selectively-turn-off-marketing-cloud-email-click-tracking/141815#141815

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that if you are using the RedirectTo() function for this link, it will tell the marketing cloud that the variable inside the RedirectTo() function is a link and should be wrapped for tracking.

You could try this on the actual unsubscribe link:

```
%%=Concat(@unsub_url, @encrypted_email_address)=%%
```