# SFMC Email Metrics

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe

Marketing Cloud E-Mail Metrics

Hello - I’m having trouble confirming this with salesforce support/documentation and would appreciate some input.

We’re trying to figure out if marketing cloud counts unsubscribes toward overall clicks in e-mail reporting. Are unsubscribes counted as clicks or are unsubscribes treated separately and not part of clicks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Every click is recorded and reported in tracking/dataviews, you can write your query to remove this based on link

SFMC also doesn't have infer opens, so you can have more clicks then opens within tracking/dataviews

Comment: in addition to that, see also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155931/is-it-possible-to-suppress-link-tracking-on-a-single-link