# Removing cl.s10.exct.net from links in Marketing Cloud Content

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to use a Dynamic link using profile variables for each subscriber on marketing cloud to send subscribers each a unique link to a for to fill out. After I set the variable using AMPScript, I use the Variable to try and link from this email to that dynamic link.

```
%%[
SET @Link = AttributeValue("URL") ]%%

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
<tr><td align="center"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
<tr><td class="innertd buttonblock" bgcolor="#18415D" style=" border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; background-color: #18415D;">
<a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; background-color: #18415D; border: 0px; padding: 26px; border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;" 

href="%%=v(@Link)=%%" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://">+ TAKE THE NEXT STEP +</a>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Every time I use this block of code I get an error after the URL is not the dynamic link, or doesn't appear to be, it appears to be wrapped in the cl.s10.exct.net that then causes the error. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your click tracking mask. You would need to remove click tracking to stop that from wrapping this URL.

You could obfuscate that it is a link via some hacky AMPscript tricks and have it so only that one is not tracked, or you could look at just removing click tracking completely from your email on setup of the send job.

Obfuscate method:

**[Official](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314602&type=1)**

```ampscript
%%[
var @URL
Set @URL = "<a href='http://google.com'>Google 1</a>"
]%%

<br>
%%=v(@url)=%%
<br>
```

An alternative option from **[SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155931/is-it-possible-to-suppress-link-tracking-on-a-single-link)**

```ampscript
%%[
var @unsubLink
set @unsubLink = Base64Encode('<a href="http://domain.com/unsubscribe">unsubscribe</a>')
]%%

%%=Base64Decode(@unsubLink)=%%
```

Now, as a note, this is the only way to stop it from wrapping. So in order to have it be the 'raw link' it means you lose OOTB insight into clicks on that URL (or all in email if you decide to do that).

Comment: Is there a way to do this solution you suggested while using the AttributeValue function to set the variable equal to an Attribute on the subscriber profile?

Comment: @Rivendare - yeah, you just CONCAT it in like `@url = CONCAT('<a href="',AttriuteValue("url"),'">myLink</a>')`

Comment: This works in preview but when I test it live the text "myLink" comes through as plain text without the hyperlink. Could I be missing something? `SET @URL = CONCAT('<a href="',AttributeValue("DynamicURL"),'">myLink</a>') %%=v(@url)=%%`

Comment: @Rivendare - Try doing a `%%=TreatAsContent(@url)=%%` instead

Comment: unfortunately the exact same result! It works and links in a preview test & send but when I try it for real it is just plain text.