# Append random number to url and strip tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, tracking

I am trying to add a random number to the end of the anchor and img urls in Marketing Cloud.  This appears to be working for the image, but I have Google tracking code in the url by default and that may be why it is not translating the AMPScript when I click the link.  That part of the link is translating like this:  &utm_term=%%%3dv(%40newurl)%3d%%

```
%%[
var @random, @num1, @num2
set @num1 = 10000
set @num2 = 99999
set @random  = random(@num1, @num2)

var @urla
Set @urla = "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/jump?iu=/12345/myad&sz=300x250&c=" 

var @urlimg
Set @urlimg = "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?iu=/12345/myad&sz=300x250&c=" 

Set @newurl = Concat(@urla, @random)
Set @newimgurl = Concat(@urlimg, @random)
]%%

<a href="%%=v(@newurl)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@newimgurl)=%%"></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it inside the RedirectTo function? It should solve your problem

Comment: I tried that.  It turns the url into a long string of characters and doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Can you post the full url?

Comment: The url that it tries to redirect to?  It comes out like this:  https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fclick.go.mydomain.com%2F%3Fqs%3D69c5417d727fd5fc56bd6695d39012deae2d26cfc8e615ace7d17070100907e16a433fa5f74b53576c6aaa24748536775e01bee1499ae2a9&data=05%7C01%7Cmrush%40mydomain.com%7Cab9ae4ff5768436d245808dadd2f0cb2%7C3f4ea757b3cf448a82d0bcb2d44f9009%7C0%7C0%7C638065491406777488%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=%2BgkVYhpizpyYTkrhPn29TN9ccrEQUjWF%2Fr1uHuvIW7M%3D&reserved=0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Base64 encode/decode trick that [@EliotHarper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155998/5202) uses.

```
%[
var @random, @num1, @num2
set @num1 = 10000
set @num2 = 99999
set @random  = random(@num1, @num2)

var @urla
Set @urla = "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/jump?iu=/12345/myad&sz=300x250&c=" 

var @urlimg
Set @urlimg = "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?iu=/12345/myad&sz=300x250&c=" 

Set @newurl = base64encode(Concat(@urla, @random))
Set @newimgurl = Concat(@urlimg, @random)
]%%

<a href="%%=base64decode(@newurl)=%%" alias="newurl"><img src="%%=v(@newimgurl)=%%"></a>
```

Comment: The random number generates fine with my code.  I can see that on the image url.  The issue is more about using AMP script with Google tracking code, which is throwing it off.  I've used Redirectto() for other links to strip the tracking code in the past, but it does not work  in this case.  For example:  <a href="%%=redirectto(@newurl)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@newimgurl)=%%"></a>

Comment: Ah, I misread your question.  Updated my answer above.  You can use the base64 encode/decode trick that @EliotHarper uses here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155998/5202

Comment: That's still not working.  It looks like this in the url:  utm_term=%%%3dbase64decode(%40newurl)%3d%%

Comment: Try adding a static alias value to your href -- `alias="newurl"`

Comment: Thanks, but that strips it down to just the SF Authenticated Domain and the tracking code.  https://click.go.mydomain.com/partnerref=Michelle+Testing&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Michelle+Testing&utm_term=newurl&utm_id=30165&sfmc_id=4998