# Why are all AMPScript links broken when "Track all links in this email" is selected?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I'm using variables to help me pre-populate email builds. When I send myself test emails with 'track all links in this email' turned on, the links no longer work. The page keeps trying to redirect.

```
VARIABLE EXAMPLE
%%[
  VAR @businessName, @url
  SET @orgName = "ACME Inc."
  SET @url = "http://acme.com"
]%%

LINK EXAMPLE
<a href="@url/%%articleID%%">%%articleTitle%%</a>

EXPECTED RESULT
http://acme.com/updates/archive/199.html
```

I've read [this article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175115/why-are-all-ampscript-links-broken-when-track-all-links-in-this-email-is-selec) but it didn't help me. Maybe because I'm not understanding how to use **redirectTo()**. If that's the case please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link example is malformed.

You need to call the AMPScript variable via v() in order to insert the value into the 'live' HTML. There are other functions that will also output the value, for instance in your case I would utilize concat()

See below:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT(@url, '/', articleID))=%%">%%articleTitle%%</a>
```

Without the RedirectTo() holding the CONCAT, it will not be included as a trackable link.