# Support for deep-Linking Salesforce | Need to update “apple-app-site-association” file

Tags: ios, deep-linking

We are trying to setup an Email - App based linking between Salesforce and our iOS App.
As part of this setup, Apple requires us to support something called Universal link (see the link provided below).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

As per the instructions, I am expected to setup a configuration file called 'apple-app-site-association' in the website (Salesforce in this context) and provide the App details in a JSON format.

Although it may sound simple when think of Static resource, the expectation is that the file is required to be placed in the root of the Salesforce domain

Such as
http://xxxx.salesforce.com/apple-app-site-association.

I was surprised that this file already exists in Salesforce but I can't edit it to add my App related information to it.

Has anyone come across this issue before, if so please provide me some insights in resolving the same.

Comment: Here's a good [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141332/possible-to-selectively-turn-off-marketing-cloud-email-click-tracking) with some details.